# How to hide the visibility of SetContentView layout of fragment in xamarin android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using the below link for qr scanning in my fragment.

https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Samples/Android/Sample.Android/MainActivity.cs

Code:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    // Initialize the scanner first so we can track the current context
    MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Activity.Application);
    //Create a new instance of our Scanner
    scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
    var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.surface_qrcode, null);   
    Task.Run(() => ScanQRCode());

    return view;
}

void ScanQRCode()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
    Activity.RunOnUiThread(async () =>
    {
        // Update the data fetched/calculated on the UI thread;
        scanner.UseCustomOverlay = true;       
        //Inflate our custom overlay from a resource layout
        zxingOverlay = LayoutInflater.FromContext(Activity).Inflate(Resource.Layout.surface_qrcode, null);

        //Set our custom overlay
        scanner.CustomOverlay = zxingOverlay;

        //Start scanning!
        var result = await scanner.Scan(new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions { AutoRotate = true });        
        HandleScanResult(result);
    });
    }).Wait();

}
```

Actually I am using customised layout for qr scan screen. So now the issue is the fragment already contains SetContentView layout. And in the OnCreate view again i am inflating the layout to display the scanning screen. So when the application runs, first the fragment layout is displaying for 2 sec and then the scanning screen is opening.
        How can i hide the fragment set content layout loading in xamarin android. Please help me with this..I treid different ways but didnt work.

Comment: fragment already contains `SetContentView` layout what does it mean, The code you given there is no `SetContentView`

Comment: I mean fragment already has a layout at this line var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.surface_qrcode, null);

Comment: And in the OnCreate view again i am inflating the layout to display the scanning screen.. Where is this OnCreate, is it in activity or fragment?

Comment: I mean to say in oncreate view i am calling ScanQRCode method. Inside that method i am inflating the scanning layout. So two layouts are getting called one after the other. But as per my requirement when we call this fragment from anywhere directly the qr scan screen should display instead of two screens